# Cant get the material-date-time-picker to show

Tags: angular, dart, angular-material, angular-dart, angular-components

I have been making a production scheduling web application. Back-end aside, it uses a angular-dart on the front with angular-components where possible. One such place is a `material-date-time-picker` for selecting the scheduling times.

I have implemented it in my job_detail.html template like so:

```
<div style="height: 600px; width: 500px; display: inline-block">
 <material-date-time-picker [(dateTime)]="dateTime"
                            [required]="true">
 </material-date-time-picker>
</div>
```

with the following imports etc. in my job_detail.dart file:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'data_service.dart';
import 'job.dart';
import 'oven.dart';
import 'Primitve_wrapper.dart';
import 'date_service.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/utils/browser/window/module.dart';


@Component(
selector:'job-detail',
styleUrls: const['package:angular_components/app_layout/layout.scss.css','job_detail.css'],
directives: const[formDirectives, CORE_DIRECTIVES, materialDirectives, ],
templateUrl: 'job_detail.html',
pipes: const [COMMON_PIPES],
providers: const[materialProviders,windowBindings,]
)
```

and still, the best it can muster is rendering the blank parent div than encloses the material-date-time-picker component. If I inspect the elements, it shows that this component has been assigned the class _ngcontent where it should be assigned _nghost and then populated with the time picker and date picker component as it is in the demo. Must be missing something here, but what?

Thanks for you help,

Brooke

Comment: Is there any errors in the browser console? I'm surprised this would run with a dart:io import in a web context for one.

Comment: You have a number of issue in your code, although assuming you pass the right data into the date picker it should work. You need to remove the dart:io import as this is not available in browsers. Also you need to use best practice for imports: dart > packages > local

Comment: I hear you. I realised It was because the date-picker component was only added in the most recent alpha version not v0.8.0 which I was depending on. However, it says no version exists when depending on - angular_components: "^0.9.0-alpha+13"